# WPF Inculding a UserControl in another UserControl with multiple bindings on DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to include a UserControl named HintBox (TextBox with watermark) in another UserControl named FormatBox (TextBox which reset the text on lost focus if it doesn't match a given Regex).

HintBox XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <Border Background="White">
        <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Text="{Binding Hint, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Visibility="{Binding HintVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </Border>
    <TextBox Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</Grid>
```

HintBox Code Behind CS :

```
// Text of the HintBox
public static readonly DependencyProperty CS_TEXT_PROPERTY = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(String), typeof(HintBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextValueCallback)));
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CS_TEXT_PROPERTY); }
    set { SetValue(CS_TEXT_PROPERTY, value); }
}
private static void OnTextValueCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is HintBox hintbox && e.NewValue is string value)
    {
        if ((value ?? "") != "") hintbox.HintVisibility = "Hidden";
        else hintbox.HintVisibility = "Visible";
    }
}

// Hint text of the HintBox
public static readonly DependencyProperty CS_HINT_PROPERTY = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Hint), typeof(String), typeof(HintBox));
public string Hint
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CS_HINT_PROPERTY); }
    set { SetValue(CS_HINT_PROPERTY, value); }
}

#region Properties
// Visibility of the hint
public string HintVisibility
{
    get { return GetProperty<string>(); } // implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    set { SetProperty<string>(value); } // implements INotifyPropertyChanged
}
#endregion
```

FormatBox XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <local:HintBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Hint="{Binding Hint,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"  FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</Grid>
```

FormatBox Code Behing CS :

```
// Text of the FormatBox
public static readonly DependencyProperty CS_EXAMPLETEXT_PROPERTY = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(String), typeof(FormatBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, null, new CoerceValueCallback(OnTextValueCoerce)));
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CS_EXAMPLETEXT_PROPERTY); }
    set { SetValue(CS_EXAMPLETEXT_PROPERTY, value); }
}
private static object OnTextValueCoerce(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    if (baseValue is string value && d is FormatBox formatbox)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value ?? string.Empty, formatbox.RegexString ?? string.Empty))
            return baseValue;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

// Hint text of the FormatBox
public static readonly DependencyProperty CS_HINT_PROPERTY = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Hint), typeof(String), typeof(FormatBox));
public string Hint
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CS_HINT_PROPERTY); }
    set { SetValue(CS_HINT_PROPERTY, value); }
}
```

MainWindow XAML :

```
 <!-- Test FormatBox -->
<controls:FormatBox Grid.Row="3" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" RegexString="^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$" />
```

My problem is that the Regex control isn't resetting the Text of the FormatBox when I enter wrong Text and make it loose focus.
But it is working if I call a modified version of the FormatBox using a TextBox instead of my HintBox like so :

FormatBox XAML (with TextBox) :

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"  FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</Grid>
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong here, could you help me figure it out?

Comment: Have you tried adding `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` to the declaration of `CS_TEXT_PROPERTY`?

Comment: Be aware that there is a mandatory naming convention for the identifier fields of dependency properties. The field must be named `TextProperty` for a property named `Text`.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. @Arkane I have tried to put FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault on the Text DependencyProperty in the HintBox.cs and FormatBox.cs and apparently it solved everything.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. Sorry for not respecting conventions, I am still learning but I will try my best to code properly. I know that there is a way to declare coventions in VisualStudio IDE and throw compilation errors or warning if they are not repected, I will look how to setup that.